# How does the window service write message to event log correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, event-log

I wrote a windows service use the Event Log for logging. It has wrote message to Event Log successfully but the message description has been appended the following text:

> The description for Event ID ( ... ) in
>   Source ( ... ) cannot be
>   found. The local computer may not have
>   the necessary registry information or
>   message DLL files to display messages
>   from a remote computer. You may be
>   able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to
>   retrieve this description; see Help
>   and Support for details.

I use C# and EventLog class in .Net for logging. How do I remove that text?

Comment: Is your service running at the same machine or a remote one?

Comment: Maybe post the line of code you use to write the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the EventLog that is available in the ServiceBase class? Do you install the service with installutil.exe? This method properly installs the event source.

Comment: I'm using the EventLog in System.Diagnostic namespace. Microsoft guided on MSDN about the EventLog as follows: "...You can configure a new source using an EventLogInstaller, or using the CreateEventSource method. You must have administrative rights on the computer to create a new event source...." so I used the CreateEventSource() method instead of EventLogInstaller.

Comment: Please look at the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx

Comment: Well I don't know about that, but in your service class, there should be a property named EventLog, too. It's a good practice to use that. InstallUtil also knows this property, and will create the source for you. And it's proven to work.

Comment: My problem is not the windows service work or not, it is the strange text was appended to the description entries in my event source in the Event Viewer.

Comment: I know, I suspect the event source is not installed correctly, that's what causes that message. That's why I suggested you use the pre-defined eventsource.

Comment: Ok fejesjoco, I'm doing as follows your advice. Thank

Comment: The description of message doesn't appear the strange text but my own source was not created, all messages have been appeared in "Application".